# How to query the last sent SMS from content provider?

Tags: android, listview, sms, android-contentprovider

When I send an SMS on my Android emulator, it goes to the content provider:

```
content://sms/sent
```

right?

So I wanted to get the last sent SMS from the content provider. So I used this Uri as you can see above and I used the method query, with the Content Resolver Object. And I got the cursor, and used the movetofirst() method, so I would have the last sent SMS. Check the code below.

```
package com.sys;

import android.app.Activity;  
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.database.Cursor;

    public class SMS extends Activity {

Button btnVerSms;
EditText txtFinal;

final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnVerSms= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerSms);
    txtFinal =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFinal);   

    btnVerSms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,  null);                                   
        String body = null;    

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();               
        }
        txtFinal.setText(body);
    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Hello, when I send an SMS on my
>   Android emulator, it goes to the
>   content provider: content://sms/sent
>   right?

Not necessarily. You assume that content provider exists on all devices and is used by all SMS client applications. Those are not valid assumptions.

> So I wanted to get the last sent SMS
>   from the content provider.

[That content provider is not part of the Android SDK.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html)

Comment: So what content provider that exists in all devices and is used by all SMS client app you suggest me to use, since this one I mentioned is not part of the framework. What URI should I pass to the query() method?

Comment: @psyhclo: There is no "content provider that exists in all devices and is used by all SMS client app", any more than every email application ever written for the desktop uses the Outlook API. Each email application, if it has an API, has its own API. Similarly, each SMS client application, if it has an API, has its own API.

Comment: So, what am I suposed to do? If I let this the way it is, my app will have serious problems. right? What should I do?

Comment: @spyhclo: Eliminate the feature that depends on your being able to read the SMS outbox.

Comment: @CommonsWare: What would be this feature? I dont get it when you say when it depends of me being able to read the SMS outbox. You want to say that I should be able to read everything, the outgoing and the incoming SMS?

Comment: @pyshclo: You wrote "So I wanted to get the last sent SMS from the content provider." Simply don't do that.